# What does each number represents in MNIST?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, mnist

I have successfully downloaded MNIST data in files with .npy extension. When I print the few columns of first image. I get the following result. What does each number represent here?

```
a= np.load("training_set.npy")
print(a[:1,100:200])
print(a.shape)

[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3  18
18  18 126 136 175  26 166 255 247 127   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0  30  36  94 154 170 253 253 253 253 253 225 172 253 242
195  64   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]

(60000, 784)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3  18
    18  18 126 136 175  26 166 255 247 127   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0  30  36  94 154 170 253 253 253 253 253 225 172 253 242
    195  64   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

These are the intensity values (0-255) for each of the 784 pixels (28x28) of a MNIST image; the total number of training images is 60,000 (you'll find 10,000 more images in the test set).

`(60000, 784)` means 60,000 samples (images), each one consisting of 784 features (pixel values).